# SAS Update selected values in one dataset based on another dataset

Tags: sas

I'm trying to update the values for city in table A from table B, but only in cases where city is "missing" in table A (I understand that this may seem like an odd case, but it is what I am needing to do).

### **Table A**

| ID | City | OtherVar1 | OtherVar2-10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Scranton | data1 | data12 |
| 002 | Tampa | data2 | data13 |
| 002 | Lansing | data3 | data14 |
| 002 |  | data4 | data15 |
| 003 | Lexington | data5 | data16 |
| 003 | Santa Fe | data6 | data17 |
| 003 |  | data7 | data18 |
| 003 |  | data8 | data19 |
| 004 | Phoenix | data9 | data20 |
| 004 | Denver | data10 | data21 |
| 005 |  | data11 | data22 |

### **Table B**

| ID | City |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Los Angeles |
| 002 | Fargo |
| 003 | Des Moines |
| 004 | Denver |
| 005 | Newark |
| 006 | Seattle |

### **Updated Table**

| ID | City | OtherVar1 | OtherVar2-10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Scranton | data1 | data12 |
| 002 | Tampa | data2 | data13 |
| 002 | Lansing | data3 | data14 |
| 002 | **Fargo** | data4 | data15 |
| 003 | Lexington | data5 | data16 |
| 003 | Santa Fe | data6 | data17 |
| 003 | **Des Moines** | data7 | data18 |
| 003 | **Des Moines** | data8 | data19 |
| 004 | Phoenix | data9 | data20 |
| 004 | Denver | data10 | data21 |
| 005 | **Newark** | data11 | data22 |

I feel like this should be straightforward, but I am not sure how to accomplish this in SAS. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why do you not want to change the value of CITY to FARGO for every observation where ID='002' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a simple MERGE to do this.  Rename the new value of CITY from the transaction dataset so its value is matched to all of the replicates in your base dataset.

```
data want;
  merge base transaction(rename=(city=new_city));
  by id;
  city = coalescec(city,new_city);
  drop new_city;
run;
```

If you want to modify the existing dataset instead of making a new one (be careful as this could destroy your data) you could use the UPDATE statement of SQL.

```
proc sql;
update base a
  set city = (select city from transaction b where a.id=b.id)
  where id in (select id from transaction)
    and missing(city)
;
quit;
```